# How to make field in List in JasperReport Ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I want my field values in one line in iReport with semicolon separator to each other. My problem is, I dont know how to make it loop in iReport.

```
 EmpName Values from database (test, test1, test2, test3)
```

I want the output like this in iReport:

```
 test; test1; test2; test3
```